# „Festhalten“ im Sinne von „konstant halten“ – getrennt oder zusammen?

Tags: spelling, compound

In der Physik oder Mathematik spricht man oft vom *festhalten* einer Grösse, etwa einer Temperatur. Beispielsweise:

> Die Temperatur des Gases wird festgehalten, indem der Behälter in einem Wärmebad platziert wird.
>
> Die Ableitung erfolgt hier nach *x*, während *y* festgehalten wird.

Ich wüsste gern, ob dieses getrennt geschrieben werden muss, oder als *festhalten*. Im Duden habe ich Folgendes entdeckt:

> BEDEUTUNGSÜBERSICHT für festhalten:
>
> durch Zupacken, Ergreifen daran hindern, sich zu entfernen; nicht  loslassen
>
> gefangen halten
>
> in Bild, Ton o. Ä. fixieren, aufzeichnen
>
> feststellen, konstatieren
>
> sich fest an jemandem, etwas halten, anklammern, um nicht zu fallen
>
> von jemandem, etwas nicht abgehen;
>
> jemanden, etwas nicht aufgeben

Diese Bedeutung ist also nicht beschrieben.

Falls man es getrennt schreiben muss, wüsste ich gern, wie man mit dem Nomen verfährt. *Das Festhalten* macht keine Probleme, aber *das feste Halten* hat eine andere Bedeutung.

---

Da angenommen wurde, es könne sich um eine Marotte eines einzelnen Dozenten handeln, habe ich recherchiert. Siehe hier:

[Fluid Dynamics I](https://books.google.de/books?id=qGfpCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&source=bl&ots=qgaoUBRC6Z&sig=lL96l4NLHhPPyJGF0e-RkpZONZc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix27q01vDNAhVE2BoKHcCpDCQQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&f=false)

[Einführung in die Festigkeitslehre für Studierende des Bauwesens](https://books.google.de/books?id=nDeBBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA10&lpg=PA10&dq=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&source=bl&ots=J_KvyN0t-6&sig=EGxv1ppIX7DK04Thinb6NL8x2-M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix27q01vDNAhVE2BoKHcCpDCQQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&f=false)

[Theorie und Anwendung der unendlichen Reihen](https://books.google.de/books?id=M3-IBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA357&lpg=PA357&dq=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&source=bl&ots=FY23yM_UVr&sig=1ZuvXMAfl40QT_M9oks2WI71Mgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix27q01vDNAhVE2BoKHcCpDCQQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=bei%20festgehaltenem%20x&f=false)

Alle diese Texte enthalten die Phrase und eine Google-Suche nach „bei festgehaltenem *x*“ liefert zahlreiche mehr.

Comment: Für mich ist die gewünschte Bedeutung die erste, nur dass es sich hier nicht um ein mechanisches Greifen handelt, aber ein "Eingreifen" mit dem Zweck, dass sich die Temperatur nicht entfernt.

Comment: Wieso sollte man es getrennt schreiben müssen? Außer in Fällen wie "Wir halten die Größe x in diesem Experiment fest". Es kommt hoffentlich noch wer, der den passenden Ausdruck dafür kennt. Die Temperatur wird am fallen gehindert (und am steigen), der erreichte Wert wird nicht aufgegeben usw. - insofern sehe ich die Bedeutung vom Duden durchaus erfasst. "Das Festhalten der Temperatur macht keine Probleme." Zusammenschreibung.

Comment: @userunknown Das klingt jetzt ziemlich überzeugend. Wahrscheinlich habe ich den Duden nicht hinreichend kreativ ausgelegt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aus den [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung:

> § 34: Partikeln, Adjektive, Substantive oder Verben können als Verbzusatz mit Verben trennbare Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie nur in den Infinitiven, den Partizipien sowie im Nebensatz bei Endstellung des Verbs zusammen.
>
> Dies betrifft:
>
> 1. Zusammensetzungen mit einer Verbpartikel als erstem Bestandteil. […]
> 2. Zusammensetzungen mit einem adjektivischen ersten Bestandteil.
>
>    Dabei sind folgende Fälle zu unterscheiden:
>
>    1. Es kann zusammen- wie auch getrennt geschrieben werden, wenn ein einfaches Adjektiv eine Eigenschaft als Resultat des Verbalvorgangs bezeichnet (sog. resultative Prädikate), zum Beispiel:
>
>    > *blank putzen/blankputzen, glatt hobeln/glatthobeln, klein schneiden/kleinschneiden; kalt stellen/kaltstellen, kaputt machen/kaputtmachen, leer essen/leeressen*
>
>    2. Es wird zusammengeschrieben, wenn der adjektivische Bestandteil zusammen mit dem verbalen Bestandteil eine neue, idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung bildet, die nicht auf Basis der Bedeutungen der einzelnen Teile bestimmt werden kann, zum Beispiel:
>
>    > *krankschreiben, freisprechen, (sich) kranklachen; festnageln* (= festlegen), *heimlichtun* (= geheimnisvoll tun), *kaltstellen* ([politisch] ausschalten), *kürzertreten* (= sich einschränken), *richtigstellen* (= berichtigen), *schwerfallen* (= Mühe verursachen), *heiligsprechen*
>
>    E5: Lässt sich in einzelnen Fällen keine klare Entscheidung darüber treffen, ob eine idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung vorliegt, so bleibt es dem Schreibenden überlassen, getrennt oder zusammenzuschreiben.
>
>    3. In allen anderen Fällen wird getrennt geschrieben. Dazu zählen insbesondere Verbindungen mit morphologisch komplexen oder erweiterten Adjektiven, zum Beispiel:
>
>    > bewusstlos schlagen, ultramarineblau streichen, ganz nahe kommen, dingfest machen, schachmatt setzen.
> 3. Zusammensetzungen mit einem substantivischen ersten Bestandteil. […]
> 4. Verbindungen mit einem verbalen ersten Bestandteil. […]

Ich denke, dass man sowohl für den Fall 2.1 (als Ergebnis des Festhaltens ist die Temperatur fest) wie auch für den Fall 2.2 argumentieren kann. Dementsprechend ist *festhalten* als zusammengeschriebenes, trennbares Verb auf jeden Fall richtig. Wer für 2.1 argumentiert, müsste auch *fest halten* zulassen.

> § 37 Substantive, Adjektive, Verbstämme, Pronomen oder Partikeln können mit Substantiven Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie ebenso wie mehrteilige Substantivierungen zusammen.
>
> Dies betrifft:
>
> 1. Zusammensetzungen:
>
>    1. mit substantivischem Erstglied: […]
>    2. mit adjektivischem Erstglied:
>
>    > *Hochhaus, Schnellstraße, Freileitung*
>
>    3. mit verbalem Erstglied: […]
>    4. mit pronominalem Erstglied: […]
>    5. mit Elementen unflektierter Wortarten (Adverbien, Partikeln): […]
> 2. Mehrteilige Substantivierungen, […]

Es ist ziemlich eindeutig, dass nur *das Festhalten* – also zusammengeschrieben – für das Substantiv gestattet ist. Unabhängig davon, für welche Schreibung man sich im Verbfall entscheidet.

---

Ich würde fast dazu tendieren, *fest* im Beispiel eher als adverbischen Bestandteil denn als adjektivischen Bestandteil zu sehen, aber das sollte an der Diskussion nichts ändern, zumal über Adverb + Verb in den Regeln nichts explizites gesagt wird.

Übrigens handelt es sich nicht um eine Marotte einzelner Professoren, mir ist das Wort quer durch alle Fachrichtungen bekannt.

Comment: Kannst du bitte ein tl;dr in fett hinzufügen? Oft will man nur das eine Wort schnell nachschlagen und hat keine Lust so viel Text zu lesen.

Answer (score 4):

Unabhängig davon was der Duden sagt, meinem Sprachgefühl nach ist “festhalten” in diesem Kontext in Ordnung. (Im Englischen benutzt man dazu in wissenschaftlichen Texten soweit ich weiß “fix” bzw. “to fix”.)

**Zur Schreibung:** Ich würde das zusammen schreiben, also “festhalten”:

> Die Ableitung erfolgt hier nach x, während y festgehalten wird. 
>   Die Ableitung erfolgt hier nach x, während y fest gehalten wird.

“Fest gehalten” im zweiten Satz würde ich als Leser eher so interpretieren, dass y tatsächlich *in der Hand gehalten wird* und das “fest” dieses Halten nur gegenüber einem loserem Griff abgrenzt. Das ist der gleiche Bedeutungsunterschied wie beim Nomen: "das Festhalten" im Vergleich zu "das feste Halten".

Answer (score 2):

Die Antwort basiert auf einem früheren Kommentar von @userunkown

---

Wieso sollte man es getrennt schreiben müssen? Außer in Fällen wie

> "Wir halten die Größe x in diesem Experiment fest".

wo das trennbare [Partikelverb](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partikelverb) getrennt werden muss.  Die Temperatur wird am Fallen gehindert (und am Steigen), der erreichte Wert wird nicht aufgegeben usw. - insofern sehe ich die Bedeutung vom Duden durchaus erfasst.

> "Das Festhalten der Temperatur macht keine Probleme."

Also ist Zusammenschreibung angebracht.

Answer (score 0):

Obwohl Deutsch meine Muttersprache ist und ich eine naturwissenschaftliche Ausbildung habe, kann ich mich nicht erinnern, „festhalten“ in diesem Sinne gesehen zu haben. In den genannten Beispielsätzen haben wir immer „konstant gehalten“ verwendet.

Auch bei einer Google-Suche danach konnte ich keine Ergebnisse finden, die die Existenz der Phrase bestätigen würden. Von daher gehe ich davon aus, dass diese Bedeutung nicht offiziell ist und z. B. nur vom jeweiligen Professor oder Buchautor verwendet wird. Daher scheint es keine offizielle Regel zu geben.

Von der Phrase „konstant halten“ und dem [Duden-Eintrag „Konstanthalten“](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/Konstanthalten) ausgehend würde ich eher zu „Das Festhalten“ tendieren, wenn ich nicht „konstant halten“ verwenden könnte.

Comment: Ich habe in Heidelberg Physik studiert und es ständig gehört. Ob es allerdings je geschrieben wurde... Sie mögen wohl recht haben!

Comment: Es gibt einen Unterschied ob eine Größe konstant erachtet oder nur "festgehalten" wird. Z.B. findet man häufig Formulierungen wie *für einen festen Wert x ist die Abbildung f(x) definiert als...*. Das bedeutet nur, dass `x` im Rahmen der Auswertung der Funktion einen festen Wert hat. Das bedeutet nicht, dass `x` generell konstant ist.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass "festhalten" im Sinne von "den Messwert ablesen und im Messprotokoll notieren" gemeint ist?

Comment: @H.Idden Nein, kann es nicht.

Comment: Googlen Sie bei Gelegenheit einfach "bei festgehaltenem x".

Comment: Ich habe in den 1980er-Jahren in Graz Chemie und anschließend Physik studiert (zusammen 15 Semester lang, aber beides abgebrochen), und auch dort und damals wurden bei Experimenten ständig irgendwelche Größen durch geeignete Maßnahmen *festgehalten*.

Comment: Dann scheint es wohl in verschiedenen Bereichen verschieden verbreitet zu sein oder ich habe es bisher immer überlesen.