# Was ist korrekt: "Der Haken schlagende Hase" oder "Der hakenschlagende Hase"

Tags: verb, noun, separable-verb

Finde bei der Suche keine klare Antwort bzw. unterschiedliche Verwendungsweisen

Comment: Es ist wohl kein exaktes Duplikat, aber das Prinzip wurde [in dieser Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30797/festhalten-im-sinne-von-konstant-halten-getrennt-oder-zusammen) auf eine andere Frage schon mal erklärt. Ich würde bei dem Beispiel eine neue, idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung sehen. Solange der Hase nicht auf Haken, Schrauben und ähnliches eindrischt, ist "der hakenschlagende Hase" richtig ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hakenschlagen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hakenschlagen) ist ein Fachwort aus der Jägersprache.

Der Hase verprügelt hier keine Haken, er ändert in schnellem Lauf blitzartig die Richtung, um seine Verfolger abzuschütteln.

Es handelt sich also um einen hakenschlagenden Hasen, nicht um einen Haken schlagenden.

Nach §34 der [amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/) werden Partizipien mit substantivischem ersten Bestandteil zusammengeschrieben.

Comment: ha, that image of the "Haken schlagender Hase" made my day :)

Comment: Schöne Antwort, aber das stimmt halt einfach nicht. Beide Schreibungen sind richtig. Siehe  https://www.dwds.de/wb/einen%20Haken%20schlagen

Comment: @HalvarF Der Fachbegriff ist [das Hakenschlagen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hakenschlagen), Partizip *hakenschlagend*. Das hat doch weder mit einem Haken (z.B. linker) noch mit schlagen zu tun.

Comment: Natürlich hat das nichts mit einem Haken oder schlagen zu tun, aber die Bedeutung hängt doch überhaupt nicht davon ab, ob man das getrennt oder zusammen schreibt. "Der Haken schlagende Hase" und "Der hakenschlagende Hase" sind einfach nur zwei Schreibungen, die beide genau dasselbe bedeuten, die Bedeutung hängt nur vom Kontext ab.

Comment: @HalvarF Als Partizip finde ich das im DWDS überhaupt nicht. Siehe aber §34 der amtl. Rechtschreibregeln, Partizipien mit substantivischem ersten Bestandteil + Verb werden zusammengeschrieben.

Comment: § 34 ist nicht einschlägig, denn dann müßte es auch heißen *wenn der Hase hakenschlägt* (was man nicht schreibt); es geht in § 34 (3) um Verben wie *kopfstehen*: *wenn die Welt mal wieder kopfsteht*. § 36 ist der richtige.

Comment: Genau, das Verb ist nicht "hakenschlagen", sondern "Haken schlagen" (der Hase schlägt Haken, nicht haken), und der verlinkte Eintrag im Duden führt nur ein Substantiv auf, "das Hakenschlagen", das als Substantivierung natürlich immer zusammen geschrieben wird. Das Adjektiv "hakenschlagend" kann man zusammen schreiben oder getrennt (§ 36 (2))

Answer (score -5):

Also mir scheint, in manchen Gegenden Deutschlands wäre der hackenschlagende Hase richtig!
Dort werden ja auch runde oder quadratische Felder zu Beginn einer Auswahlmöglichkeit "angehackt"

Comment: .... und das ist beides ein Rechtschreibfehler. Haken sind Haken. Und Hacken sind eben Hacken (der arme Hase, der sich die Hacken anschlägt...)